# Cron job not working for Whenever gem, rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, cloud9-ide

I am using ide cloud 9
Rails 5

I instaled gem whenever.

```
gem 'whenever', :require => false
```

**schedule.rb:**

```
set :output, "#{path}/log/cron.log"

every 2.minutes do
  rake "subscription:send_mails"
end


namespace :subscription do
  desc "Send dayly mails with new projects"
  task send_mails: :environment do

    Subscriber.where.not(categories: []).find_each do |subscriber|
      projects = Project.where(categories: subscriber.categories, created_at: 1.days.ago )
      SubscriptionMailer.send_email_with_new_projects(subscriber, projects).delivery_now
    end
  end
end
```

Run in command line:

```
bundle exec whenever
0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32,34,36,38,40,42,44,46,48,50,52,54,56,58 * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/ubuntu/workspace && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake subscription:send_mails --silent >> /home/ubuntu/workspace/log/cron.log 2>&1'

## [message] Above is your schedule file converted to cron syntax; your crontab file was not updated.
## [message] Run `whenever --help' for more options.
```

Now running a local server in development mode. I don't see any evidence that the code is actually being run. log/cron.log is empty.  Is there some step that I didn't do?

Comment: From your project root, please run the `whenever` command. Does it show you your defined task in a crontab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cron jobs do not work on Cloud9 unless you're using an SSH workspace.

---

Source: [How to enable/run cron on Cloud9?](https://community.c9.io/t/how-to-enable-run-cron/2250/2?u=bradydowling)